# Literature of one-hot encoding performance v.s. others

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, categorical-encoding

For categorical classification, I couldn't find literature comparing one-hot encoding v.s. others from either theoretical or empirical point of view. I understand one-hot encoding is probably too intuitive to have any 'foundation' or 'derivation'. I also know that ordering category as scalar makes no sense. What about the compact binary encoding? On one hand we'll have fewer parameters to train and thus the model will be more robust, but on the other hand could the model using binary encoding be more sensitive to parameter fluctuation?

I guess we'd be particularly interested in the context of neural network given its popularity and prevalence.

Comment: Can you explain/reference *compact binary encoding*?

Comment: I naively think it's just binary encoding: say we have 4 classes, then only 2 bits are needed to encode them -- 00, 01, 10, 11.

Comment: Well, yes, but how do you use them in a linear model?

Comment: In neural net we are not looking for linearity. Similar to one-hot encoding, when encoded in k nodes in the last layer, we are fitting k functions.

Comment: @Shen-FuTsai than forget about “linear”, how would you use them in neutral network? The usual way is to have one-hot encoded values, where you multiply the parameters by ones and zeroes.

Comment: Nothing dramatically different: with binary compact encoding we still have zeros and ones. For example 3 is encoded to 001 and 11 by one-hot and binary compact encodings, respectively. Other encodings may result in non-binary values, but as long as they are real-valued multiplication is still well defined.